# How can I make a Command Line Step move to the next step in Azure Pipelines

Tags: azure, command-line-interface

I am running an Azure Pipeline using the classical editor and I would not like to use YAML so can you give me the answer in Classical Editor or script form please?
I run the step as a command line editor step and then it Starts the app I want it to start then it just sits on the step and does not move on to the next steps and through the stage. I do not want it to stop the app in the same step just move on to the next step.
I run this script

```
npx percy app:exec start &
  displayName: 'start cli'
  env:
```

It will sit on this step until the stage times out completely.